# How to pass an array as parameter to a task with SetParameter from OmniThreadLibrary?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe8, omnithreadlibrary

In Delphi XE8, I am trying to pass an array to the OTL task in `SetParameter` from OmniThreadLibrary:

```
implementation

type
  TCookie = record
    Name:    string;
    Value:   string;
    ExpDate: string;
    ModDate: string;
  end;

  TCookieArray = array of TCookie;

var
  CurCookies: TCookieArray;

procedure TForm1.btnStartTaskClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(CurCookies, 2);
  CurCookies[0].Name  := 'username';
  CurCookies[0].Value := 'Paul';
  CurCookies[1].Name  := 'password';
  CurCookies[1].Value := 'none';

  FGetCookieDetailsTask := CreateTask(GetCookieEntries, 'GetCookieEntries')
    .MonitorWith(OTLMonitor)
    // Compiler complaint:
    .SetParameter('CookiesArray', TOmniValue.FromArray<TCookieArray>(CurCookies))
    .Run;
end;
```

The compiler complains about the SetParameter line:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(310): E2010 Incompatible types:
'System.TArray<Unit1.TCookieArray>' and 'TCookieArray'
```

Unfortunately, there are no examples in the OTL book on how to use `FromArray` in `SetParameter` to pass an array to the task.

So how can this be done?

**EDIT**: ba__friend asked that I show the source code from my solution in the comments of his answer:

```
  FGetCookieDetailsTask := CreateTask(GetCookieEntries, 'GetCookieEntries')
    .MonitorWith(OTLMonitor)
    // Now no compiler complaint:
    .SetParameter('CookiesArray', CurCookies)
    .Run;

procedure GetCookieEntries(const task: IOmniTask);
var
  TaskCookies, HostCookies: TCookieArray;
begin
  HostCookies := task.Param['CookiesArray'];
  TaskCookies := Copy(HostCookies, 0, Length(HostCookies));
```

Comment: Delete `TCookieArray` and use `TArray<TCookie>` instead. Never declare a dynamic array any other way. Ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1) `TCookieArray` has to be declared as

```
TCookieArray = TArray<TCookie>;
```

From the compiler's standpoint, `array of T` and `TArray<T>` are (sadly) not the same thing.

2) `FromArray<T>` expects the type `T` to be the array item type, not the array type (see [OtlCommon](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/blob/6cab1ec994138ef72a189d39de7cbb7a9d4d7142/OtlCommon.pas#L1796)), so you have to change it from

```
TOmniValue.FromArray<TCookieArray>
```

to

```
TOmniValue.FromArray<TCookie>
```

To access this array from a task, call:

```
var
  cookies: TCookieArray;

cookies := task.Param['CookiesArray'].ToArray<TCookie>;
```

---

Side note: This is how things *should* work. In OTL up to (and including) 3.04b, record type is, however, not handled correctly in `ToArray<T>` and `FromArray<T>`. A fix for that has just been committed to the [GitHub](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary).

If you want to fix your copy manually, two modifications are needed.

In `TOmniValue.CastFrom<T>`, this block

```
if ds = 0 then // complicated stuff
  {$IFDEF OTL_ERTTI}
```

should be changed to

```
if ds = 0 then // complicated stuff
  if ti^.Kind = tkRecord then
    Result.SetAsRecord(CreateAutoDestroyObject(
      TOmniRecordWrapper<T>.Create(value)))
  else
    {$IFDEF OTL_ERTTI}
```

In `TOmniValue.CastTo<T>`, following block

```
if ds = 0 then // complicated stuff
  {$IFDEF OTL_ERTTI}
```

should be changed to

```
if ds = 0 then // complicated stuff
  if ti.Kind = tkRecord then
    Result := TOmniRecordWrapper<T>(CastToRecord.Value).Value
  else
    {$IFDEF OTL_ERTTI}
```

Comment: Now I have `SetParameter('CookiesArray', TOmniValue.FromArray<TCookie>(CurCookies))`. But the compiler still complains: `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(310): E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<Unit1.TCookie>' and 'TCookieArray'`

Comment: Have you tried using the generic array type in the first place? Or aliasing TCookieArray to TArray<TCookie>?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Could you provide a code example?

Comment: Something like: `type TCookieArray = TArray<TCookie>;`

Comment: Now the compiler complains: `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(310): E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<Unit1.TArray<Unit1.TCookie>>' and 'System.TArray<Unit1.TCookie>'`

Comment: Look at the code in my question -- that's how it is defined and declared.

Comment: Now I have tried using simply `SetParameter('CookiesArray', CurCookies)`. It works flawlessly. But I don't know whether it is threadsafe.

Comment: When using `SetParameter('CookiesArray', CurCookies)`, both the host program and the task SHARE the same array object - even when I use it with a task variable: `TaskCookies := task.Param['CookiesArray'];`. This means that when I write to `TaskCookies` inside the task then also `CurCookies` in the host program is affected! I am not sure whether this is threadsafe...

Comment: ...which is not the case when I COPY the array inside the task: `var TaskCookies, HostCookies: TCookieArray; begin HostCookies := task.Param['CookiesArray']; TaskCookies := Copy(HostCookies, 0, Length(HostCookies));`

Comment: If you look at the implementation of FromArray and I am not mistaken your records of type TCookie are being copied.

Comment: What exactly? FromArray? Could you please update your question with the most recent version of your source code? Thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer to include fix for both mistakes.

Comment: @gabr Thanks, and in the task? With `TaskCookies := task.Param['CookiesArray'].ToArray<TCookie>;` I get an exception at run-time: `TValue of type tkRecord cannot be converted to TOmniValue` --- Edit: Aaaah, the exception comes not from the task but from `SetParameter`: `.SetParameter('CookiesArray', TOmniValue.FromArray<TCookie>(CurCookies))`

Comment: Strange, is it the newest version of the library? Edit: Looks like it comes from [here](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/blob/6cab1ec994138ef72a189d39de7cbb7a9d4d7142/OtlCommon.pas#L2449)

Comment: @gabr Thank you very much for the quick fix! I have downloaded the new `OtlCommon.pas` from GitHub and now it works!

Comment: It's a mistake to encourage the use of anything other than `TArray<T>`. Aliases serve no purpose at all.